# How to implement remember me functionality by Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I want to build API for my mobile app. How can I implement remember me functionality for login form? I use Laravel Passport for auth. Thank you.

Comment: I don't work much with laravel but it appears laravel passport is an API authentication scheme (e.g. OAuth 2).  It isn't directly connected to a laravel login form and OAuth 2 isn't normally used for login to your website.  Can you help me understand your problem a bit more?

Comment: @Pace Yes that's right,I want every time in input parameters "remember_me=True" Keep user logged in for more time,Is there no security problem if I increase the expiration date

Comment: access_token and refresh_token,expires_in time

Answer (score 2):

For other friends who might have this question, this might help

As long as we have active refresh_token, the user can is logged

Therefore, if it is in the usual mode, for example,active for one week, we will increase this time to one month

```
//Increase the expiration time for the refresh_token
if ($remember_me == true)
   Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(\Carbo\Carbon::now()->addDay(30));

//Add secret parameter and get access_token
$request->request->add($this->parameter());
$proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');
$result = Route::dispatch($proxy);
```

Good luck